# How to preserve query parameters using IIS HTTP wildcard redirects?

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-redirect

I'm trying to configure redirects to prepare the switch from an ASP to an MVC website. The IIS wildcard redirects are working fine, but I cannot figure out how to preserve the query parameters.

Example:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent">
    <add wildcard="/EmailAddress-Verify.aspx" destination="https://foo.com/account/email-verify$Q" />
  </httpRedirect>
</system.webServer>
```

I read that `$Q` [will preserve the query params](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737576.aspx) but it's not working. Google could not find anything on that issue.. is there anything I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So this configuration was working perfectly! I just had to clear my browser cache since the redirection is `Permanent` and the browser 'remembered' my previous configuration while I was playing with the config file. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Y̶o̶u̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶e̶x̶a̶c̶t̶D̶e̶s̶t̶i̶n̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶=̶"̶t̶r̶u̶e̶"̶.̶ However, more importantly, when you want to have more granular control with redirects, you're much better off using the [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). Your bit would be something like the following (not tested and quickly written up):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Email Address Verify Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^EmailAddress-Verify.aspx(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://foo.com/account/email-verify{R:1}" />
    </rule>
 ...
 </rewrites>
```

Oh, now that I think about it, you could probably just do a straight up pattern without the following wildcard and just appendQueryString="True" in the action.

Comment: exactDestination="true" is necessary otherwise the redirection is considered as relative and I want it to be absolute.
Thanks for the tip about the URL Rewrite module, I will look into it!

Comment: Did not recall that. Thanks. Although unless it's a very basic wholesale redirect I haven't touched httpRedirect over using IISRewrite  in...well, a very long time. Most importantly, any time dealing with redirects, browser caching is a pain that often leads you down rabbit trails. Therefore I always use Fiddler or Paw (on Mac) to see exactly where things are heading and with which HTTP code.

Comment: Great advice! Makes total sense :)